# SQL/BIGQUERY Running Average with GAPs in Dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, average, moving-average, rolling-average

I'm having trouble with a moving average in BigQuery/SQL, I have table 'SCORES' and I need to make a 30d moving average while grouping the data using users, the problem is my dates aren't sequential, e.g there are gaps in it.

Below is my current code:

```
SELECT user, date,
      AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date)
FROM SCORES;
```

I don't know how to add the date restrictions into that line or if this is even possible.

My current table looks like this, but of course with a lot more users:

```
user    date    score
AA  13/02/2018  2.00
AA  15/02/2018  3.00
AA  17/02/2018  4.00
AA  01/03/2018  5.00
AA  28/03/2018  6.00
```

Then I need it to become, this:

```
user    date    score   30D Avg
AA  13/02/2018  2.00    2.00
AA  15/02/2018  3.00    2.50
AA  17/02/2018  4.00    3.00
AA  01/03/2018  5.00    3.50
AA  28/03/2018  6.00    5.50
```

Where in the last row, it's only measuring backward one because of the date (up to 30D backwards) is there any way to implement this in SQL or am I asking for too much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `range between`.  For this, you need an integer, so:

```
select s.*,
       avg(score) over (partition by user
                        order by days
                        range between 29 preceding and current row
                       ) as avg_30day
from (select s.*, date_diff(s.date, date('2000-01-01'), day) as days
      from scores s
     ) s;
```

An alternative to `date_diff()` is `unix_date()`:

```
select s.*,
       avg(score) over (partition by user
                        order by unix_days
                        range between 29 preceding and current row
                       ) as avg_30day
from (select s.*, unix_date(s.date) as unix_days
      from scores s
     ) s;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being a noob, but what is t referring to inside the FROM, statement? Cheers and thank you.

Comment: @bknight . . . It was the table name.  I missed that your question does have a table name.

Comment: man, I felt dumb now, this is working flawlessly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  AVG(score) OVER (
    PARTITION BY user 
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', date))
    RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS avg_30day 
FROM `project.dataset.scores`
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.scores` AS (
  SELECT 'AA' user, '13/02/2018' date, 2.00 score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AA', '15/02/2018', 3.00 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AA', '17/02/2018', 4.00 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AA', '01/03/2018', 5.00 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AA', '28/03/2018', 6.00 
)
SELECT *,
  AVG(score) OVER (
    PARTITION BY user 
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', date))
    RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS avg_30day 
FROM `project.dataset.scores`
```

result

```
Row user    date        score   avg_30day    
1   AA      13/02/2018  2.0     2.0  
2   AA      15/02/2018  3.0     2.5  
3   AA      17/02/2018  4.0     3.0  
4   AA      01/03/2018  5.0     3.5  
5   AA      28/03/2018  6.0     5.5
```